# Open dataGridView in new window c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am creating an application in c# that allows me to enter data into a SQL database and retrieve data from the same database. I haven't had any issues with entering data into the database. My issue is trying to retrieve the data. I created a windows form that has a search textbox and button. I added the dataViewGrid on the same form and when I search the database it fills the dataViewGrid with no issues. However, I want the dataGridView to open in a new window. I have tried creating a new form and adding the dataGridView to that form. It will open but the grid is empty.

Here is my code for searching for data and populating the grid on the same form.

```
 private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        cn.Open();
                    using(DataTable dt = new DataTable("testTbl2"))
                    {
                        

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select *from testTbl2 where firstName = @firstName or lastName like @lastName", cn))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstName", searchTxt.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastName", searchTxt.Text);
                            
                            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            adapter.Fill(dt);
                            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
                            totalLbl.Text = $"Total records: {dataGridView.RowCount-1}";

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void searchTxt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)//enter
                searchBtn.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

Edit: I have tried adding this to the button click in Form1.

displayForm f2 = new displayForm();
f2.Show(); // or f2.ShowDialog();

I read something about referencing the forms with each other but I'm not sure. I have tried about 5-6 different things I found while searching for a solution. I didn't save each attempt so without searching back through my search history, I'm not sure what they were.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far with the dgv on the 2nd form.

Comment: Your `displayForm` needs a DataGridView control and you need to set the DataSource to that DataTable results.  Right now, it looks like you are showing the results on the main form.  Mulitple ways to do this.  Passing the DataTable into a custom DisplayForm constructor, then wire it up from there.